# Inno Setup Language Dialog customization

Tags: customization, inno-setup

I just created an installer. 
I added only one custom page and a download plugin.
I changed all backgorund color (surface, wuzard, etc) to white.

But Language Dialog start before de WizardForm and is Grey!

Can i customize also Language Dialog?

Best regards

Comment: See also [Inno Setup - Language selector with VCL Styles](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41021292/850848).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't customize such window (this is a inno setup limitation)... inno setup doesn't provide any  access to the "Select Language" dialog.